# How can I use ngx translate with this select in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

```
*<div class="dropdown bootstrap-select">
  <select class="selectpicker" formControlName="gender" demon-ev="true" tabindex="-98" 
  (change)="changeGender($event)">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option *ngFor="let gender of genders" value="{{ gender.code }}">
    {{ ('gender_'+gender.code) | translate }}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>*
```

I need to translate gender. description , it can have 3 value (male,famale,undefined)
I try with string intepulation but not work , pls help me

Comment: Could you make a stackblitz of your code?

Comment: 1. Try wrapping inside a <div>.  2. Are you sure that your translations are loaded ? 3. When you select an option, does translation work ?

Comment: I follow this https://www.codeandweb.com/babeledit/tutorials/how-to-translate-your-angular-app-with-ngx-translate , and the genders coming from backend , for use this array in this select i use {{gender. code}} / {{gender. description}}. My it.json is : {
 "gender_1" : "Maschio",
 "gender_2" : "Femmina",
 "gender_3" : "Non definito"
} and i use this interface : export interface Gender {
    "id":number;
    "code" : string;
    "description" : string;
}

Comment: Your code looks fine, interpolation should work properly. Check if your translation file is correct and if it is loaded correctly. Quick stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-translate-playground-nubzfa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts